# Reduce flashing In Between Form Transition

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a set of forms in two different languages and a button that brings you to the other language.

Currently I am using form1.show() and then formEnglish.close() under my button click. However, in between it is flashing and showing the desktop.

I tried:

1) Double Buffering the form

2) SuspendLayout() and ResumeLayout()

but neither of these helped

Is there anyway for the forms to transition smoothly from one to the other?

Comment: Are you saying, you're opening the same form object only using different language?

Comment: No, they are similar boards, with the same amount of buttons and controls, so was hoping that there would be a smoother transition

Comment: One form has to go and another must open. Try `me.Hide, form.Show, me.Close` and on the form that shows put `me.show` first line in `form_load`

Comment: Still heavy blinking

Comment: You must have lots of controls pre-loading. Like lists, is it?

Answer (score 0):

If the only difference between the forms is the language then you might want to look in to proper localization techniques.

If you are fixed on your current plan you might be able to get it working by first loading the new form that has it's bounds exactly match the current form, but displayed behind it.  Then let the application handle pending events (to paint the new form), and then closing the old form.  You may need to use a slight timer delay after showing the new form, and before closing the old one to make sure it is fully loaded.